# Color items content like in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, richtextbox

I'd like to do very basic syntax highlighting inside my ListView. I'd like to be able to colorize my ListView's items. For example highlighting text between parentheses, etc.

Is it only possible? If so then do you have any example on how to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ListViewItem.ForeColor(set) to set a color to a given item or text.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.forecolor.aspx

To change the background color, use backcolor

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/FadingListView.aspx here it show's how to colorize item's inside the ListView

Comment: Thanks it could be useful but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like to put multiple colors / backgrounds / fonts inside the same cell like in a RichTextBox. I guess it is not possible using the stock RichTextBox...